# How many recipients can be added to BCC in python django

Tags: python-2.7, email, smtp, gmail, django-1.6

How many maximum number of recipients can be added at a time to BCC field while sending a bulk e-mail?

I'm using python Django framework and gmail, smtp for sending mail.

Comment: Dunno about Django specifically, but unless you have reasons to believe it artificially imposes a limit, there isn't one.

Comment: ... though Gmail might get nervous if you host a high-volume mailing list through your Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

BCC limit for Gmail: 500 in any 24 hours period.

If you want to send emails in bulk, you will need to request it as 500 per request.